# Is it possible to have multiple APK support based on country?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have an application that has free and priced products, I need to create two APKs for my application and show the application that supports In-App Billing in the countries that support it and show another APK of the same application that doesn't support In-App Billing (It has only the free products) in the countries that don't support it.

Can I use the Android Market Multiple APK Support feature to achieve this? If not, is there any feasible suggestions other than creating tow separate applications?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Multiple APK feature AFAIK does not support filtering country at least in the current release. Check out [Supported filters](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#SupportedFilters) and [Rules for multiple APKs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#Rules) for more details.

If you are going to build two apks anyway. It is much simpler and easy-maintainable to publish them as two standalone application (where you can differ and set available country for each in developer console), other than using Multiple APK feature (says even it supports filtering country in the future release). A normal way people used to avoid duplicate code is using Android Library Project.

If you only want to build and publish a single apk for all cases. a feasible solution could be maintain a supported country list in project resource and add some conditional branch to enable/disable in-app billing code based on the country list, and acknowledge user with some UI warning at runtime, something like:

```
if (isInSupportedCountryList()) {
  setInAppBillingOn();
} else {
  setInAppBillingOff();
}
```

As you can see, this needs (even not necessary) updates/re-publish every time new countries are supporting or removed by Google.

Comment: Nice explanation!. But would it possible to achieve this, if we just maintain the country listing for each update as per the requirement? For eg., if at version say x, we upload an apk for a country say A(only) and then upload a version x + 1 for another country B(only). Will doing this un publish the app in the country A?

Comment: I do not think the conditional if based on countries work because you cannot publish your app to countries without in-app billing support even if you disable it in the code.

Comment: The problem is that if I want to add a new string, I ever have to translate that string to all the languages I already translated my app or I don't translate the strings and have an app half translated...

Comment: How would that isInSupportedCountryList() function look like? How can you determine the country of a user?

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest thing would be to just upload two separate applications and then use the "Publishing Options" to select which countries you want to have each version.  Then you can add and remove either application on a 'per country' basis.

[image]

Answer (score -5):

You can achieve this by localizing your application. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Comment: I am afraid that you didn't get what I am asking. This has nothing to do with localization. What I need is to show different APK in different countries for the same application