# Google Play Console - Multiple APK for different country

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap, google-play-console

I explain my problem.

**Current situation**

We are delivering an application that must be released for 2 separated country, in details i have 2 myApp.apk (package name "com.my.app") built and signing with the same key but both have some hardcoded javascript configurations that are different (not in the manifest but only in the app code).

**Build system**

We are building with the phonegap service so i haven't the full control on the manifest created.

**Goal**

Publish the apk diversificate for country visibility.
eg. italian users can see the app "MyApp" which has an IT sever configuration wrote in the code and swiss users can see them app called with the same name but that contains different configuration.

**What we tried**

1. In the play console i tried to add another app project calling it with a different name (with the same package name of the previous one just published) but when i finish the upload google said me that currently an application with the name "com.my.app" already exist

**Question**

Is exist a way to diversificate the second application based on the delivery country?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple APK support based on country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703267/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-apk-support-based-on-country)

Comment: why you don't use in same project two interface if user from italian show index1.html if the user from country 2 show index2.html ? and in google play add a specific name to every country
because you can't use same id for two apps

Comment: Hi Tomin. 

Yes i saw that question but the problem is different. We are speaking about publishing (aka google play filtering). 
Sorry

Comment: Hi younes, 
yes yes i know this is the way that i'd like to take but unfortunately not know. We are in some late with the publishing and know the user's country is not different due to some project's entities limit. 

We need to implement this mechanism sure, but not now ;( 

Very thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two apps with the same package name targeted on country. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703267/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-apk-support-based-on-country) gives a good explanation on why.

So you have two options:

1. Release your app with two different package names, eg com.myapp.it and com.myapp.de
2. Have your app change configuration based on country using something like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/)

Which answer will be best depends on the use case. For your use case, the second option sounds best.

Comment: Hi Nick. Yes i just saw this answer, but reading some article i just saw the country field as probably filter (i thought that is was configurable directly into the manifest). 

But ok, we are following the first way for this first release (the second is not applicable to my case due to the fact that we differentiate client by a server logic and not by our firebase db) :) 

Thanks anyway man