# Can i have 2 Productions version with different country in Google Play Console and Apple Store Connect?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store-connect, google-play-console

I need help on something.

I would like to have two different versions in **production **.

I would like my two versions to have
different countries.

For exemple, 1.0 version available for US and 2.0 version available in Spain

I searched the internet and couldn't find anything about this.

Is this possible for you?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: There are ways to go about this, but you might want to explain why you need different versions out there for different countries.  There are ways in iOS/Android to handle localization within one app version.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I hope this thread might solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/48204645/22324209

Comment: do you need this temporary or permanently?